# gawk: simulate uniq -cd for 1 or more multifield files, merging duplicates details and formatting output with counts and paths

Tags: awk, duplicates, unique, multiple-columns

input is 1 or more files containing list of filenames with their paths, separated with '/'
(from rearranged ls/dir output)

```
   file1 / path1
   file2 / path2
   file3 / path3
   file4 / path4
   file3 / path5
   ...
```

desired output is similar except for duplicates for which I would like their individual counts and associated paths
(either on the same line, separated with '/' or indented after each duplicates filenames):

```
1 / file1 / path1
1 / file2 / path2
2 / file3 / path3-1 / path3-2
1 / file4 / path4
...
```

or

```
1 / file1 / path1
1 / file2 / path2
2 / file3 / path3-1
            path3-2
1 / file4 / path4
...
```

for now I have some big awk mess, at least it does something but I hope their is more concise, light and perhaps faster way of doing it! since I didn't find how to avoid storing all lines in tmp var...

```
gawk -F/ -v "tot=c" "{a[$1]++;l[$1]=$1;m[$1]=$2;if (a[$1]>1) m[$1]=m[$1]FS$2;} END {for (i in a) {print a[i],FS,l[i],FS,m[i]; c+=a[i]};print c}" file1 file2 > out
              ^                                                    ^ here, it doesn't keep      ^
              ^                                                      prev path and add new      ^
              ^                                                                                 ^[*]
```

So, the problem is to keep previous paths of duplicates and only output it with each last occurrences.

:[*]: additionally:
the added var c is supposed to count the overall number of duplicates, which it does if I add ' if (a[i]>1) ' at the asterisk' position (it(s then output as the last line), but then printing only dups...
So, better than running this command twice, maybe someone will come with a solution in one go :)

nb:
their is no / in the paths, they are windows paths (nor in filenames!)
but path and filenames can contain any allowed fancy char (especially webpage shortcuts)
using Gnuwin binaries in MSdos batch, so replace " with ' &v/v if needed

Thank you

Comment: What are file1 and file2 for your command since you have shown one one input file.

Comment: @anubhava they are all the same format, just other dir (ls) output from other paths. Note that the command works with 1 or more input files, the sorting (uniques or duplicates) is on the first column (filenames) only and I need to keep paths linked

Comment: why did `path3` and `path5` change values?

Comment: @karakfa same file can be in different locations (folders, drives, anywhere...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F/ -v OFS=' / ' '{c[$1]++; v[$1]=($1 in v?v[$1] OFS:"")$2} 
                    END {for(k in c) print c[k],k,v[k]}' file

1 /  file1  /  path1
1 /  file2  /  path2
2 /  file3  /  path3 /  path5
1 /  file4  /  path4
```

however, this won't work if you have `/` in your path values...

Answer (score 0):

Given input.txt containing:

```
   file1 / path1
   file2 / path2
   file3 / path3
   file4 / path4
   file3 / path5
```

and pgm.awk containing:

```
BEGIN{
  FS="/"
}
{
  a[$1] = a[$1] "/" $2
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    n=split(a[i], b)
    if(n == 2){
      print n-1 "/" i  a[i]
    } else {
      p=n-1 "/" i
      for(j=2; j<=n; j++){
        p=p "/" b[j] "-" j-1
      } 
      print p
    }
  }
}
```

running:

```
gawk -f pgm.awk input.txt
```

outputs:

```
1/   file1 / path1
1/   file2 / path2
2/   file3 / path3-1/ path5-2
1/   file4 / path4
```

Comment: ok but like I mentioned paths (foldernames) and filenames can contain any allowed char, that is all ascii, unicode, other languages, what ever, thus including spaces. That's why I've chosen '/' as separator since it's the only forbidden char for filenames and foldernames I am filtering upstream, and both on linux and windows

Comment: I changed the .awk to use only '/'. Hope it can help.